# Что не так с кодом или чего не хватает для решения задачи

Tags: c++, c

Цель задачи ввести массив и сравнить элементы массива с заранее вводимым числом и вывести количество элементов меньше числа,но оно выводит с начало не понятные для меня числа и откуда они взялись,а потом не правильное количество элементов.
Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int rows=4,cols=4;
    int i,j,k,sum1;
    int k1=0;
    int matz[rows][cols];
    printf("Введите число чтобы сравнить его с элементами массива: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Введите элементы матрицы %d строки ,%d столбца\n\n",rows,cols);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        printf("matz[%d][%d]=",i,j);
        scanf("%d",&matz[i][j]);
    }
    puts("Матрицы имеет вид:");
    for(i=0;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        printf("%4d",matz[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (matz[i][j] < k)
    {
        k1++;
        sum1+=matz[i][j];
    }
    printf("Количество элементов меньше k равно %d",sum1);
    return 0;
}
```

Неправильный вывод программы:

```
Введите число чтобы сравнить его с элементами массива: 14
Введите элементы матрицы 4 строки ,4 столбца

matz[0][0]=2
matz[0][1]=3
matz[0][2]=-7
matz[0][3]=4
matz[1][0]=5
matz[1][1]=-2
matz[1][2]=0
matz[1][3]=3
matz[2][0]=1
matz[2][1]=-6
matz[2][2]=9
matz[2][3]=5
matz[3][0]=2
matz[3][1]=1
matz[3][2]=4
matz[3][3]=8
Матрица имеет вид:
   2   3  -7   4
   5  -2   0   3
   1  -6   9   5
   2   1   4   8
1968224   01971040   0
Количество элементов меньше k равно 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
for(i=0;i<=rows;i++)  // тут ваша первая ошибка
{
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    printf("%4d",matz[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

вы выходите за пределы массива и выводите целую строку неопределенных значений. Исправьте на:

```
for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) // определите i в цикле
```

Вы не замечаете свои же ошибки наверняка потому что пишете без отступов. Дальше еще хуже: В цикле `i` принял значение  `rows`, а вы используете его:

```
//вторая ошибка. Это нужно занести в цикл
if (matz[i][j] < k) 
{
    k1++;
    sum1+=matz[i][j];
}
```

И зачем вы выводите за пределы цикла переменную, предназначенную для подсчета цикла?  Определяйте ее прямо в цикле, как я  показал...